# TortoiseGit, ignore line endings

Tags: tortoisegit

I am looking for a way to prevent TortoiseGit from flagging files as changed when they have Unix line endings. It is just tough to check if remote files have changed when you FTP download a folder, they show up as changed often because of the LF version that comes down. I'm on Windows, the repos are CRLF, but as I said when they change on the server they end up as LF.

Comment: look at the autocrlf setting

Comment: Not worried about commits or checkouts. I FTP download a directory to make sure that the remote server files match what is in the local repo. There is a chance that another dev uploaded a file and did not commit/push it. The files on the webserver will sometimes have the line endings changed to LF, assuming because of edits in Cpanel or the Wordpress editor. So when I download a theme, TortoiseGit flags a ton of files as changed, it it tedious to check each one in a merge tool, and or change the line endings just to make sure the files match.

Comment: make local config autocrlf false (updated my answer)

Answer (score 13):

1. Right click in that repository, TortoiseGit -> Settings
2. Turn local AutoCrlf OFF and apply the setting
   [image]

---

Extra ref.

Read [Dealing with line endings - Per-repository settings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#per-repository-settings),

then try [Dealing with line endings - Refreshing a repository after changing line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings)

Comment: By doing so TortoiseGit keeps showing every single file with only line ending differences. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case all local files was showing change in newline chars. When I looked closely the 'CRLF' was converted to 'LF'. If I change the LF to CRLF manually, it was not working as in GIT repo it was showing it as difference in file.
I also tried  Yue's changes but while clicking on Apply button it was asking me windows hook file, that I do not had.

Then i realized that recently I had installed "cygwin" on my system. I was done using that, so I removed it and restarted system, and all my problems gone.
My answer may help someone in my situation.